# Wordpress - Delete custom-post-type post

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add a button in wordpress that deletes a custom-post-type post with a specific title and current user as author.

Problem that occurring is that all the posts gets deleted, all the job_alert posts, not only for this specific author or with this title.

Can someone see why?

```
$delete_post = array(
    'post_type'     => 'job_alert',
    'post_title'    => $title,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => $current_user->ID
);
    $posts = new WP_Query( $delete_post );

if ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
        $posts->the_post();
         wp_delete_post( get_the_ID());
    }
}
```

I also have this code that creates a post and that works great. Similar code.

```
$new_post = array(
    'post_type'     => 'job_alert',
    'post_title'    => $title,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => $current_user->ID
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post( $new_post );
```

Comment: does your query work as intended? Use `var_dump(get_the_ID())` inside The Loop to see how many posts the response contains

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For deleting the particular post, here is the solution,

Please use `name` parameter instead of `post_title` in your query, then only it will return the required post which you want.

I have modified your code. Please find the updated code below:

```
$delete_post = array(
    'post_type'     => 'job_alert',
    'name'    => $title,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => $current_user->ID
);
```

Now, your required post will be returned.

Hope, this may be helpful to you and let me know, if you have any query.
Thanks.

Comment: Glad, it helped you. Thanks:)

Comment: One more question regarding this topic; The code you provided works great but not with names containing ÅÄÖ. Any idea why?